# Static Spacetime = no cosmological constant?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, cosmological-constant, adm-formalism

I stumbled over a strange result, which cannot be true: In the (3+1)-formulation of general relativity, one considers a metric of the type

$$g_{\mu\nu}\mathrm{d}x^{\mu}\mathrm{d}x^{\nu}=(-\alpha^{2}+\beta_{i}\beta^{i})\mathrm{d}t^{2}+2\beta_{i}\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}x^{i}+h_{ij}\mathrm{d}x^{i}\mathrm{d}x^{j}$$

The Einstein equations in vacuum are then equivalent to a set of evolution and constraint equations for the $3$-metric and the extrinsic curvature $k$, which read

$$\partial_{t}h_{ij}=-2\alpha k_{ij}+\mathcal{L}_{X}h_{ij}$$
$$\partial_{t}k_{ij}=\alpha\bigg(R(h)_{ij}+kk_{ij}-2k_{ik}{k^{k}}_{j}-\Lambda h_{ij}\bigg)-\nabla_{i}\nabla_{j}\alpha+\mathcal{L}_{X}k_{ij}$$
$$k_{ij}k^{ij}-k^{2}-R(h)+2\Lambda=0$$
$$\partial_{i}k-\nabla_{j}{k_{i}}^{j}=0$$

where all the objects are written down with respect to the $3$-metric $h$ (i.e. covariant derivative, Ricci tensor, raising/lowering indices, trace, ...)

Now, let us choose $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=0$. That is no loss of generality, just merely a choice of coordinates ($\alpha,\beta$ are freely specifiable and a choice of them corresponds to a gauge choice). Furthermore, let us assume that the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ is static, i.e. $h_{ij}$ is independent of time. In this case, the equations simplify and are given by

$$0=-2k_{ij}$$
$$\partial_{t}k_{ij}=\bigg(R(h)_{ij}+kk_{ij}-2k_{ik}{k^{k}}_{j}-\Lambda h_{ij}\bigg)$$
$$k_{ij}k^{ij}-k^{2}-R(h)+2\Lambda=0$$
$$\partial_{i}k-\nabla_{j}{k_{i}}^{j}=0$$

Now, the first equation implies that $k_{ij}=0$ and hence, we find the following two equations

$$R(h)_{ij}-\Lambda h_{ij}=0$$
$$-R(h)+2\Lambda=0$$

The trace of the first equation is equal to $R(h)-3\Lambda$ and hence, this system can only be satisfied if $\Lambda=0$ and $R(h)=0$. However, this seems to be not quite correct, since there are static vacuum spacetime solutions with non-zero cosmological constant (i.e. just take the Schwarzschild-de Sitter spacetime). So, where is the error in my arguments?

Comment: With your choice of gauge $\alpha=1$ and and definition of "static", the Killing vector $\partial_t$ has norm $1$. However, in the static solutions you are referring to this global time-like Killing vector has norm $\sqrt{ 1 + \Lambda r^2 } $ at large distances. I think what's happening is that by assuming that your global time-like Killing vector has norm 1 you are restricting yourself to solutions with $\Lambda = 0$.

Comment: Okay. So, you basically say that my definition of "static" is more restrictive then what is usually meant by static spacetimes? Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: I would say a static metric is one that can be recast into the form $ds^2 = - \alpha(x) dt^2 + h_{ij}(x) dx^i dx^j$ for an arbitrary $\alpha(x)$ and metric $h_{ij}(x)$ none of which depend on $t$. If wanted to go back to your gauge and set $\alpha = 1$, then $h_{ij}$ would no longer be independent of $t'$ (the newly define time coordinate)

Comment: Essentially, you'll roughly need to do a coordinate transformation which takes $t \to \frac{t'}{\sqrt{\alpha}} + \cdots$. The problem is that the first term will necessarily mix $t'$ with $x$ so you'll end up with cross terms $dt' dx$ in the metric. To fix this, you'll also need to do a $t'$-dependent coordinate transformation for $x^i$, i.e. $x^i \to x'^i + \cdots$ where the $\cdots$ depend on $t'$. Consequently, the new metric $h'_{ij}$ will no longer be independent of $t'$ thus failing your criteria for static, despite actually being static.

Comment: Ah okay, I see. So, indeed, requiring $\alpha=1$ and a time-independent $h$ in this choice seems to be a stronger assumption then what is usually meant by "static". This also matches the example of Schwarzschild de Sitter mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The De Sitter metric with cosmological constant Λ can be expressed [dependent](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/27.html) on time if you use comoving coordinates and [independent](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/28.html) if you express it in the Schwarzschild Droste form, so your assumption is incorrect.

Comment: Okay, but still I don't understand. If the metric can, for some choice of coordinates, be written in the form $-\mathrm{d}t^2+h_{ij}$ for coordinate time independent $h$, the derivation of my question applies and leads to the conclusion $\Lambda=0$....