# Ultrastatic spacetime and cosmological constant

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, cosmological-constant

A spacetime $(\mathcal{M},g)$ is called "ultrastatic", if it admits a set of coordinates such that
$$g=-\mathrm{d}t^{2}+h$$
where $h$ is a Riemannian metric, which does not depend on time. Does there exists an example of a spacetime, which solves Einstein field equations with cosmological constant $\Lambda\neq 0$ **in vacuum** which is ultrastatic? Following my question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/741408/static-spacetime-no-cosmological-constant) and the proposed answers and comments, I would expect not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are none. According to the paper ["Ultrastatic spacetimes" by Sebastiano Sonego](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.1714), for any ultrastatic spacetime,

$$Λ=\frac12 κ (T_{ab} η^a η^b + T_{ab} h^{ab}) \tag{2.6}$$

(where $η$ is the Killing field), so $Λ=0$ if $T=0$.

More informally, the integral curves of the Killing field are geodesics in an ultrastatic spacetime, so a ball of test particles "at rest" will not change in size, which seems to be inconsistent with a lambdavacuum.